# Deploy to WAS Liberty Profile without jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, websphere-liberty, ibm-rad

I have an application running on WebSphere Application Server 8.0 that I'm trying to migrate to WebSphere Liberty Core 16.0.0.4.

It uses jax-ws, but it includes all required cxf libraries and contains DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true in the manifest, so the jax-ws feature of Liberty should not be required.

However, when I try to publish that application in Rational Application Developer 9.6 it responds with "Application [EAR project] ([Utility module]) requires feature 'jaxws', which is not supported by WebSphere Application Server Liberty".

What do I need to modify to allow publication of my application to WebSphere Liberty (without installing the jaxws-2.2 feature)?

Comment: What facets do you have selected? To see, right-click on your project and choose Properties > Project Facets.    This can influence the features that are added to your server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on your project and choose Properties > Liberty > Required Features, the jaxws-2.2 feature should be in the list. Set the Action to Never Add, and it shouldn't try to add the unsupported feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately jaxws-2.2 is not in the list for the utility module with the error (the list is empty). The WAR module correctly lists jsp-2.3 and jdbc-4.1 as Required Features.